# Does any know of a Algorithm that allows for a figure like this image?

Tags: algorithms

Does anyone know how to create an algorithm capable of making the figure just like in the picture, when given a set of specific points (3D array)

[image]

Comment: It's a thing, is this what you are looking for: http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio Post that as an answer so I can upvote it please  ;) (but not just the link, some minimal explanation of the algorithm would be necessary for an answer)

Comment: @YannisRizos I would, but I don't have any knowledge or experience in this kind of thing, so I could not give you an adequate explanation (well I could, but others could do much better) The only reason I knew the link is because I knew the name of the shape from Blender (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Primitives)

Comment: creating the shadow from a 3D object is done daily, check out [shadow mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping) and [shadow volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping), but there are more shadow creation algorithms available

Comment: It's not the Shadow I'm looking to create, it's the physical object. We're going to 3D print it.

Comment: Many standard programs designed to create CGI video effects would be able to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Coming here after the battle, but since there are no accepted answer yet and seeing that @Luke refuses to get the rep he deserves, here is a quick summary of the link he provided.

So the full algorithm is available here:

http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html

The idea is to bootstrap your mesh with a simple method which gives you a sphere with 20 faces, and then refine it until you are satisfied.

### Bootstrapping the shape

You start with an [icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron). As the wikipedia article says, you can obtain the vertices by drawing three identical and orthogonal rectangle. You have 3 rectangles with 4 corner each --> 12 vertices.

Wikipedia illustration:

[image: icosahedron]

For example, the Z plan points are (a, b are the rectangle lengths):

- (+a, +b, 0)
- (-a, +b, 0)
- (+a, -b, 0)
- (-a, -b, 0)

Now you still have to find the 20 faces. This is left as an exercise to the reader :p

### Refining the shape

Now that you have a basic sphere, you may want to add polygons. You do so with this simple algorithm:

```
for each iteration:
    # each iteration multiplies by 4 the number of faces
    for each edge at the current iteration:
        split the edge in two
        replace the middle point on the sphere
```

To find the middle point, we suppose that we wish to create  the unit sphere (center (0, 0, 0), radius 1).

```
middlePoint(p1, p2):
    middle = Point((p1.X + p2.X / 2), # same for y, z)
    radius = sqrt(middle.X^2, middle.Y^2, middle.Z^2)
    return Point(middle.X / radius,  # same for y, z)
```

At each iteration, we may have to reconstruct the faces, but it is fairly easy. Each face is divided into four:

[image: face refine]